# extracting the attribute value from a header in camel

Tags: apache-camel, xquery

The input looks like below,

```
<book author="ABC" type="Children">
    <id>123</id>
    <name>XYZ</name>
</book>
```

I have set the above in header in an xml route as:

```
<camel:setHeader headerName="REQUEST">
    <camel:xpath>/node()</camel:xpath>
</camel:setHeader>
```

Now, I want to extract the value of an author(i.e. ABC) from this header and set it as another header. I tried using the following code but it failed.

```
<camel:setHeader headerName="AUTHOR">
    <camel:xquery type="java.lang.String">{data($REQUEST/@author)}</camel:xquery>
</camel:setHeader>
```

What should be the correct way to extract set the header?

Comment: Why not set the `AUTHOR` header at the same time you set the `REQUEST` header? The xpath to the author attribute would be straight forward.

Comment: I have to set the second header only if some operation is successful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct way to set this header is:

```
<camel:setHeader headerName="AUTHOR">
    <camel:xpath>in:header('REQUEST')/@author</camel:xpath>
</camel:setHeader>
```